# Auto-indexing enum ids within structure

Tags: c++, enums, indexing

I have the following `enum`'s within a `struct`:

```
struct FOODS
{
    enum FRUIT
    {
         ORANGE,
         BANANA,
         PINEAPPLE
    };

    enum VEG
    {
        GINGER,
        GARLIC,
        ONION
    };

    enum DRINK
    {
        WATER,
        COFFEE
    };
};
```

I'm using them as array index ids for `std::vector` like `array[FOODS::FRUIT::ORANGE]` but I need them to be indexed properly in the sequential order. I could use:

```
struct FOODS
{
    enum FRUIT
    {
         ORANGE = 0,
         BANANA,
         PINEAPPLE
    };

    enum VEG
    {
        GINGER = 3,
        GARLIC,
        ONION
    };

    enum DRINK
    {
        WATER = 6,
        COFFEE
    };
};
```

But then I'd have to manually manage all three enums if any of two on the top gets changed. What better way could it be?

Comment: `GINGER = PINEAPPLE + 1,` could help maybe ... Though you have an arguable design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion 1:**

```
struct FOODS
{
    enum FRUIT
    {
         ORANGE,
         BANANA,
         PINEAPPLE,
         FRUIT_SIZE
    };

    enum VEG
    {
        GINGER = FRUIT_SIZE,
        GARLIC,
        ONION,
        VEG_SIZE
    };

    enum DRINK
    {
        WATER = VEG_SIZE,
        COFFEE,
        DRINK_SIZE
    };
};
```

*Note:* You can't do it as next:

```
struct FOODS {
    enum FRUIT
    {
         ORANGE,
         BANANA,
         PINEAPPLE,
         SIZE
    };

    enum VEG
    {
        GINGER = FRUIT_SIZE,
        GARLIC,
        ONION,
        SIZE
    };

    enum DRINK
    {
        WATER = VEG_SIZE,
        COFFEE,
        SIZE
    };
};
```

...because you woluld have name redeclaration (`FOODS::SIZE`).

**Suggestion 2:**

```
struct FOODS
{
    enum class FRUIT
    {
         ORANGE,
         BANANA,
         PINEAPPLE,
         SIZE
    };

    enum class VEG
    {
        GINGER = FRUIT::SIZE,
        GARLIC,
        ONION,
        SIZE
    };

    enum class DRINK
    {
        WATER = VEG::SIZE,
        COFFEE,
        SIZE
    };
};
```

`enum class` solve the names overlaping scoping the enums.
Notice that strong enums (`enum class`) is supported since C++11.